# java nested loop patterns

Tags: java, loops, nested

I am having issues with nested loop to print a pattern. While most tutorials show a pyramid mine is more complex.

I need to print the following based on user input for the # of rows, for example:

**2 rows:**

```
o //\\.
o//  \\.
```

**4 rows:**

```
o   //\\.
o  //  \\.
o //    \\.
o//      \\.
```

This is what i've tried so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Homework {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // int size = 2;
        int noOfRows = 3;

        //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How Many Rows You Want In Your Pyramid?");

        // int noOfRows = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Here Is Your Pyramid");

        for (int i = 1; i <= noOfRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("o");
            //Printing i*2 spaces at the beginning of each row

            for (int j = noOfRows * 2 + 1; j >= 1; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            //Printing j value where j value will be from 1 to rowCount

            for (int j = noOfRows + 1; j >= 1; j--) {
                System.out.print("//");
            }

            //Printing j value where j value will be from rowCount-1 to 1
            for (int j = noOfRows + 2; j <= noOfRows; j++) {
                System.out.print("\\" + "\\" + ".");
            }

            System.out.println();

            //Incrementing the rowCount

        }
        System.out.println(); // NEWLINE

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
How Many Rows You Want In Your Pyramid?
Here Is Your Pyramid
o       ////////
o       ////////
o       ////////
```

Output does not print the pyramid. How can I fix my code to get the expected result? any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: in your 4 row example output your 2nd row is longer than your 2nd row in your 2 row example is that really what you  mean?

Comment: Ahh i messed that up, should look like the 2 row but all in line, ill try to edit.

Comment: Please explain what 'issues' exactly you are getting, including the incorrect output or error stacktrace you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should print the first half with '//' symbol and the another half with '\.' symbol, for to do that you need some for loops, check the example with the explanation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Number of rows
    int nRows = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i <= nRows; i++) {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        string.append("o");

        for (int k = i; k <= nRows; k++) {
            // Adds a white space before the first '//' symbol
            string.append(" ");
        }

        // Adds the '//' symbol
        string.append("//");

        int z = (i + i) / 2;

        for (int j = 1; j <= z; j++) {
            // Adds the first half of white space between the '//' and '\\'
            string.append(" ");
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= z; j++) {
            // Adds the second half of white space between the '//' and '\\'
            string.append(" ");
        }

        // Adds the '\\\\.' symbol
        string.append("\\\\.");

        // Prints the string
        System.out.println(string);

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
o     //\\.
o    //  \\.
o   //    \\.
o  //      \\.
o //        \\.
```

**UPDATED**

For the "o" inverse:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Number of rows
    int nRows = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i <= nRows; i++) {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

        for (int k = i; k <= nRows; k++) {
            // Prints a white space before the first '//' symbol
            string.append(" ");
        }

        // Prints the '//' symbol
        string.append("//");

        int z = (i + i) / 2;

        for (int j = 1; j <= z; j++) {
            // Prints the first half of white space between the '//' and '\\'
            string.append(" ");
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= z; j++) {
            // Prints the second half of white space between the '//' and '\\'
            string.append(" ");
        }

        // Prints the '\\\\.' symbol
        string.append("\\\\.");


        for (int k = i; k <= nRows; k++) {
            // Prints a white space before the '\\.' symbol
            string.append(" ");
        }
        // Prints white spaces before the 'o' at the end
        string.append("o");
        System.out.println(string);

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
     //\\.     o
    //  \\.    o
   //    \\.   o
  //      \\.  o
 //        \\. o
```

Comment: Awesome, so if i wanted the "o" inverse what would you suggest? I need to read up on string.append. have not covered that in class yet.

Comment: check the update

Comment: Wow, Thanks.... how do you guys do this so fast. i spent 12 hours playing and never got it.

Comment: you're welcome!, with a little more practice you will get it easily

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int noOfRows = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("o");
            for(int j=0; j< noOfRows; j++) {
                if(i+j == noOfRows-1)
                    System.out.print("//");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }

            // Inversing previous logic
            for(int j=noOfRows-1; j>= 0; j--) {
                if(i+j == noOfRows-1) {
                    System.out.print("\\\\.");
                    break;
                }
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
o   //\\.
o  //  \\.
o //    \\.
o//      \\.
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Firoz Memon, Thanks. its exactly what i need to get the rest completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Pyramid {
    private static final String leftDesign = "//";
    private static final String rightDesign = "\\\\.";
    private static final String startPointDesign = "o";

    private static String getSpace(int input) {
        String temp = startPointDesign;
        for (int i=0; i< input-1; i++) {
         temp += " ";
        }
        return temp;
    }

    private static String getPyramidDesign(int tempSpace) {
        String temp = leftDesign;
        for (int i=0; i < tempSpace; i++) {
            temp += " ";
        }
        temp += rightDesign;
        return temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //assign your input
        int input = 10;
        int tempStartCount = 0;
        int tempReverseCount = input;
        for (int i = 0; i< input; i++) {
            if(i != 0){
                tempStartCount +=2;
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("%s%s", getSpace(tempReverseCount), getPyramidDesign(tempStartCount)));

            tempReverseCount --;
        }
    }
}
```

test: input = 4

```
o   //\\.
o  //  \\.
o //    \\.
o//      \\.
```

test: input = 10

```
o         //\\.
o        //  \\.
o       //    \\.
o      //      \\.
o     //        \\.
o    //          \\.
o   //            \\.
o  //              \\.
o //                \\.
o//                  \\.
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you are after.

```
public class Homework {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int noOfRows = 10;
        System.out.println("How Many Rows You Want In Your Pyramid?");
        System.out.println("Here Is Your Pyramid");
        for (int i = 1; i <= noOfRows; i++) {
            StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
            string.append("o");

            for (int k = i; k <= noOfRows; k++) {
                string.append(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                string.append("//");
            }

            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Krishnan Mahadevan, its half of what i need. i will try to adapt the rest based off your example.